# What to do with deleted question that is off topic for this site

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I posted a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772011/no-page-information-in-search-results-magento-2-1-8

Then realised that it doesn't belong on stack-overflow and deleted it. I got the answer in the correct community now.

What should I do with this question? Should I just leave it? I don't want to move it as I posted another question, almost the same, and got my answer now. I can't really improve the question as it is completely off topic for this site.

Comment: Posts with delete votes are only soft-deleted. OP's, users with > 10K reputation and moderators can see deleted posts. That is by-design. No further action is needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ve deleted it; it’s “gone”, and when I try to get at it (I’m not a privileged user at Stack Overflow), I see that it’s 404, removed by author. *You* may be able to see it and undelete it, but users who do not have sufficient privilege on the site cannot, so there’s no need for you to do anything else.

Comment: Great :) Thank you :)

Comment: @Ale - what was the reason for the de-smartquoting edits?

Comment: Smartquotes are dumb. If that's your style, then fine. I've restored them, but by using the characters instead of the HTML entities.